# Detect if slow animations is on / off in iOS Simulator in code

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, core-animation, ios-simulator

I want to programatically detect if slow animations is on or off in simulator.

Something like this would be handy.

```
IPHONE_SIMULATOR_SLOW_ANIMATIONS_ENABLED()
```

This is for development purposes only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately it's easy:

```
float UIAnimationDragCoefficient(void);

static inline BOOL slowAnimationsEnabled()
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return UIAnimationDragCoefficient() != 1;
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about that one!

Comment: Unfortunately Apple broke it in iOS 7.

Comment: Christian, it still works in iOS 8. See my solution that also works on 64 bit.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz Thanks for reporting the 64 bit incompatibility. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's not that easy. Have a look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/89223f37e2764c283767) by [0xced](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21698/0xced) for how to make slow CAAnimations in the simulator.

Answer (score 3):

How to do this in Swift 3.0:

```
@_silgen_name("UIAnimationDragCoefficient") func UIAnimationDragCoefficient() -> Float

func slowAnimationsEnabled() -> Bool {
    return UIAnimationDragCoefficient() != 1.0
}
```

Note that unfortunately you can't use `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` at compile time in Swift, and you should not include this in your App Store submissions as you may be rejected for using private APIs.

Comment: Well, then this is using private API. Your app might be rejected in app store, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you should not build for the app store with this in your code (you shouldn't need this for the app store at all however).  My suggestion is to use this on a separate build target and define a custom Swift flag that will not include this when building for the store.

Comment: `#if targetEnvironment(simulator)` is now available (since Swift 4.1).

Answer (score 2):

I defined this function that returns the factor to multiply animation durations with (1 if slow animations are disabled, the slowness factor otherwise):

```
CGFloat FTSimulatorAnimationDragCoefficient(void) {
    static float (*UIAnimationDragCoefficient)(void) = NULL;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UIAnimationDragCoefficient = (float (*)(void))dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "UIAnimationDragCoefficient");
    });
#endif
    return UIAnimationDragCoefficient ? UIAnimationDragCoefficient() : 1.f;
}
```

Note that I use `float`, not `CGFloat` as the return type of the called `UIAnimationDragCoefficient()` function. This is needed to work with the 64 bit simulator.

Then I can simply multiply the animation duration:

```
CAAnimation animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.duration = 0.5 * FTSimulatorAnimationDragCoefficient();
```